# Linq GroupBy and multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

```
class ExpenseClaim
{
    int EmployeeId;
    int Team;
    double Cost;
}


List<EmployeeExpense> GetEmployeeExpenses()
{
    return _expenseClaims // `_expenseClaims` is `List<ExpenseClaim>`
             .GroupBy(e => e.EmployeeId)
             .Select(x =>
                new EmployeeExpense(
                        x.Key,
                        // TODO: employee team?
                        x.Sum(e => e.Cost)
                );
}
```

Excuse the rather contrived example.

How do I get the employee team in `GetEmployeeExpenses`? I'm assuming I need a second group by but I can't work out the syntax.

Note that for a given employee, their `Team` will always be the same anyway, so I'd be happy to take the `Team` of for example the first grouped by record.

so...

```
ExpenseClaim { EmployeeId = 1, Team = Sales, Cost = 100 }
ExpenseClaim { EmployeeId = 1, Team = Sales, Cost = 50 }

=>

EmployeeExpense { EmployeeId = 1, Team = Sales, Cost = 150 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your particular case, you could use `x.First().Team` inside your Select to get your team information.

For other cases of actually needing to group on multiple fields, you could group on an anonymous type. Such as

`someQuery.GroupBy(f => new { f.Foo, f.Bar }).Select(...);`

Comment: +1 Good answer pointing out that he could use `First` for his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Query expression version of it (*might* be easier to read, depending on situation and amount of grouping):

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeExpense> GetEmployeeExpenses(List<ExpenseClaim> claims)
{
    return 
        from c in claims
        group c by c.EmployeeId into groupedById
        from g in groupedById
        group g by g.Team into groupedByTeam
        let firstElement = groupedByTeam.First()
        select new EmployeeExpense {
            EmployeeId = firstElement.EmployeeId,
            Team = firstElement.Team,
            Cost = groupedByTeam.Sum(e => e.Cost)
        };
}
```